# How have a form open on button click in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to find the right syntax and code that will open a Form (settings.cs) so the user can edit my program to their likings!

- I don't want the current form to close.

Comment: Are you trying to save the values a user is entering on a Windows form to your settings.cs file

Comment: My Program is a Web browser and in the settings.cs is where they edit the Home URL. So, yes i am trying to save the values, but how is this going to help me open a Form?

Comment: Is your app runs within browser or it is Windows Form app which needs to open from on top of itself?

Comment: 1,013,185 c# questions...do you really think this has not yet been asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a form either dynamically or in the gui. I'd advise to use the gui as formatting can be iffy when done dynamically. As far as calling a form you must use the following:

```
void btnSettings_On_Click(){
Form somename = new YourFormName();
somename.Show() // or somename.ShowDialog(); if you want the new form to have priority until it is closed
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked! But I have this error now.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0122 'settings.homeURL' is inaccessible due to its protection level WebNavigator c:\users\jefferson\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebNavigator\WebNavigator\Form1.cs 42 Active

Comment: Can you edit your original post and post the newly added code

Comment: I have to wait 2 days!

Comment: I am assuming at some point in your code you used the Settings class, which is an internal type. You will have to right click on your project >> properties >> Settings. In the upper bar just below the file tabs There Should be some text "<>View Code" and Access Modifier: Internal that has a drop down, change that to Public and try to run it again. @ZombieKnifer223

Comment: I am at settings part but I see is "Settings string user" and nothing you said.

Comment: nevermind I see it (derp)

Comment: No worries, its kinda hidden. I wish I couldve sent a picture, but let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Partial declarations of 'Settings' have conflicting accessibility modifiers

Comment: Okay, I have managed to find the problem myself. There was a cs file named "settings1.cs" that was conflicting with other things. I managed to fix it! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: glad to see it has worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "Form2" with your form's name:

`//give user exclusive control of Form2
new Form2().ShowDialog();`

`//give user control of both forms
new Form2().Show();`